# The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type orbital_app

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

1. This is the code. My main frame is orbital_app and I would like it to when I click on JButton (button), data is being saved, the current window closes and another window orbital_app opens.

   ```
   public class signup_try {

       private JFrame frame;
       private JTextField txtname;
       private JTextField textusername;
       private JTextField txtpass;
       private JTextField textmail;

       /**
        * Launch the application.
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       signup_try window = new signup_try();
                       window.frame.setVisible(true);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       /**
        * Create the application.
        */
       public signup_try() {
           initialize();
       }

       Connection connection=null;

       /**
        * Initialize the contents of the frame.
        */
       private void initialize() {

           connection=dbase.dBase();
           frame = new JFrame();
           frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

           JLabel label = new JLabel("Orbital");
           label.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
           label.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 17));
           label.setBounds(170, 11, 71, 25);
           frame.getContentPane().add(label);

           JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Name:");
           label_1.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
           label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
           label_1.setBounds(21, 66, 46, 14);
           frame.getContentPane().add(label_1);

           txtname = new JTextField();
           txtname.setColumns(10);
           txtname.setBounds(102, 63, 200, 22);
           frame.getContentPane().add(txtname);

           textusername = new JTextField();
           textusername.setColumns(10);
           textusername.setBounds(102, 108, 200, 22);
           frame.getContentPane().add(textusername);

           txtpass = new JTextField();
           txtpass.setColumns(10);
           txtpass.setBounds(102, 150, 200, 22);
           frame.getContentPane().add(txtpass);

           textmail = new JTextField();
           textmail.setColumns(10);
           textmail.setBounds(102, 192, 200, 22);
           frame.getContentPane().add(textmail);

           JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Username:");
           label_2.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
           label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
           label_2.setBounds(21, 111, 71, 14);
           frame.getContentPane().add(label_2);

           JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Password:");
           label_3.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
           label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
           label_3.setBounds(21, 154, 71, 14);
           frame.getContentPane().add(label_3);

           JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("Email:");
           label_4.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
           label_4.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
           label_4.setBounds(21, 196, 46, 14);
           frame.getContentPane().add(label_4);

           JButton button = new JButton("Sign Up");
           button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

   try {

                       String query="insert into Users(Name, Username, Password, Email) values(?,?,?,?)";
                       PreparedStatement prepstat=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                       prepstat.setString(1, txtname.getText());
                       prepstat.setString(2, textusername.getText());
                       prepstat.setString(3, txtpass.getText());
                       prepstat.setString(4, textmail.getText());

                       prepstat.execute();

                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved");



                       prepstat.close();

                   } catch (SQLException e) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                   }
   ```
2. I get the error saying that `The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type orbital_app`. what should I do to fix this? Here I want to close this present frame(signup_try) and go to other frame (orbital_app).. setVisible is underlined red and says `"The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type orbital_app"`.

   ```
                   frame.dispose();
                   orbital_app orb=new orbital_app();
                   orb.setVisible(true);


               }
           });
           button.setBounds(170, 239, 91, 23);
           frame.getContentPane().add(button);
       }
   ```

   ### }

Orbital_app code(in this code setVisible works properly without any error):

```
package project;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.SystemColor;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class orbital_app{

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    orbital_app window = new orbital_app();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Create the application.
     */




    public orbital_app() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 260);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel toplbl = new JLabel("Orbital");
        toplbl.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        toplbl.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 17));
        toplbl.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        toplbl.setBounds(182, 11, 71, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(toplbl);

        JLabel infolbl = new JLabel("Multipurpose app ==  orbital 1.0\r\n");
        infolbl.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        infolbl.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        infolbl.setBounds(138, 47, 165, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(infolbl);

        JButton signup_btn = new JButton("Sign Up");
        signup_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.dispose();
                signup_form sup_for=new signup_form();
```

3.setVisible works here

```
                sup_for.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        signup_btn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        signup_btn.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        signup_btn.setBounds(61, 133, 91, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(signup_btn);

        JButton signin_btn = new JButton("Sign In");
        signin_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                frame.dispose();
                signin_form log_for=new signin_form();
```

4.and here too

```
                log_for.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        signin_btn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        signin_btn.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        signin_btn.setBounds(285, 133, 91, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(signin_btn);

        JLabel notelbl = new JLabel("note: click Sign Up for new account or Sign In for existing account.");
        notelbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        notelbl.setBounds(10, 199, 406, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(notelbl);
    }



}
```

Comment: You should probably show the `orbital_app` class too.

Comment: I assume you have a class `orbital_app`? And you really need to format your code properly when pasting it in your question.

Comment: orbital_app is another frame and i want that when i click the button in present frame (signup_try) it takes me to that frame(orbital_app)

Comment: Its not a `JFrame,` its a `orbital_app`. It might inherit from `JFrame`, but we don't know that for sure, cause you don't show the class. From the error you describe, it sounds like it does not though.

Comment: i have posted my code for orbital_app.. need ur help guys i really dont know wt the problem is.. seVisible is working in orbital_app but not working in signup_try

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, it is solved by exteding the `JFrame` class.
Your class should extends `JFrame`, because setVisible() method belongs to `JFrame`class.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide more context, use comment instead

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a few issues with your code.

Most importantly: You have multiple entry points in your program.
You should only have one `public static void main(String[] args) ...` function in your application, that is where the 'program starts'.

The error message you get (`The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type orbital_app`) comes from the fact that the class `orbital_app` don´t have a `setVisible` function, one of its members does, but that doesn't matter.

Your `orbital_app` have a private member that is a `JFrame`, which makes it possible for you to call the `JFrames` methods from inside the `orbital_app` by accessing the frame, but you cant reach it from outside.
It seems you have mixed up inheritance and ownership.

If you wish your `orbital_app` class to be a `JFrame`, you need to inherit from the `JFrame`. Else you could just implement the methods you wish to make public for your other classes.
Or you could just create a getter for the private `JFrame` object so that you can access it from outside.